# How can I set a default handler for urls that don't match any endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm dealing with a ASP.NET Core Web API program.
As we all know, when the url doesn't match any endpoints, the server will automatically return 404 code.

Now that I want the service to record these requests into a log, so I want to set a default handler for them.
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably can be solved by adding a middleware. I tried this:

```cs
namespace ExampleServer
{
    public class NotFoundMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<NotFoundMiddleware> _logger;

        public NotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<NotFoundMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await _next(context);

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning($"{context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Path} cannot be reached.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add code in startup to use this middleware:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
// ...
app.UseMiddleware<NotFoundMiddleware>();
```

Then Profit. The output in log is like this:

```
warn: ExampleServer.NotFoundMiddleware[0]
      GET /notfounduri cannot be reached.
```

But this only implements log the unreached urls. To set a default handler (like return a certain page), use the following code:

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/example_sdk/v1/dont_execute/404");
```

You may replace the endpoint to any expected name, and add a controller with the same name to handle it. Here is an example:

```cs
[HttpGet("/example_sdk/v1/dont_execute/404")]
[HttpPost("/example_sdk/v1/dont_execute/404")]
[HttpDelete("/example_sdk/v1/dont_execute/404")]
[HttpPut("/example_sdk/v1/dont_execute/404")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public JsonResult EndPoint404()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("404 controller reached.");
    var rtn = new
    {
         retcode = -1,
         msg = "System Error"
    };
    return new JsonResult(rtn);
}
```

Now, we fulfilled the two requirements: "record these requests into a log" and "set a default handler for them". Notice that the middleware is executed before the handler:

```
warn: ExampleServer.NotFoundMiddleware[0]
      GET /notfounduri cannot be reached.
info: ExampleServer.Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
      404 controller reached.
```